# I need to translate the English .txt file to German language using AWS translate service and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am able to convert particular English words to German words. But I am looking to convert the entire local.txt file.

```
import boto3

translate = boto3.client(service_name='translate', region_name='us-east-1', use_ssl=True)

result = translate.translate_text(Text="Good Evening", 
        SourceLanguageCode="en", TargetLanguageCode="de")
print('TranslatedText: ' + result.get('TranslatedText'))
print('SourceLanguageCode: ' + result.get('SourceLanguageCode'))
print('TargetLanguageCode: ' + result.get('TargetLanguageCode'))
```

I am looking for a way to convert the streaming data or local text file and then save it to S3 or locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have an AWS account, I can't test the API directly. However, I can offer what I believe would work.

First, read the text file you want to translate into a variable.

```py
with open('text_to_translate.txt', 'r') as text:
   variable_containing_text = text.read()
```

Then, simply feed the translator the variable, rather than a string.

```py
result = translate.translate_text(Text=variable_containing_text, 
        SourceLanguageCode="en", TargetLanguageCode="de")
```

When placed into your code, it should look like this:

```py
import boto3

data = 'file.txt'

translate = boto3.client(service_name='translate', region_name='us-east-1', use_ssl=True)

with open(file, 'r') as text:
   data = text.read()

result = translate.translate_text(Text=data, 
        SourceLanguageCode="en", TargetLanguageCode="de")
print('TranslatedText: ' + result.get('TranslatedText'))
print('SourceLanguageCode: ' + result.get('SourceLanguageCode'))
print('TargetLanguageCode: ' + result.get('TargetLanguageCode'))
```

Comment: I tried using the below code

 `code`

import boto3

data = 'file.txt'

translate = boto3.client(service_name='translate', region_name='us-east-1', use_ssl=True)

with open(r'C:\Users\ashish\Documents\AWS S3\file.txt', 'rb') as text:
   data = text.read()

result = translate.translate_text(Text=data, 
            SourceLanguageCode="en", TargetLanguageCode="de")

print('TranslatedText: ' + result.get('TranslatedText'))
print('SourceLanguageCode: ' + result.get('SourceLanguageCode'))
print('TargetLanguageCode: ' + result.get('TargetLanguageCode'))

Comment: The answer is correct but there is a small mistake. Instead of `with open(file, 'r') as text:` you have to put `with open('file.txt', 'r') as text`. There is no variable name file. I have tried this on my account and it works.

Comment: Is there a way to use particular directory apart using one particular file and saving the output in some particular path. For example: Converting all the files that are present in some particular folder an then saving the converted files in some particular path.

Comment: Use following to save output to text file. ``code`` file = open("sample.txt","w")
file.write(result.get('TranslatedText'))
file.close()

Comment: Ninad, thanks for correcting that mistake, I see where the problem is :p

Comment: @AshishBansal Yes you can loop through a directory using os.listdir() https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm

Comment: @NinadGaikwad I tried but unable to make it work, can you suggest the code for it.